# How to update Services in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

The problem is simple yet complicated. I have Created a data model in silverlight and its services. Now I've changed the Database. Added a field in one of the table, and updated the data model. Now I've to update the services that i'd created before. I don't want to delete the previous service. Is there any way through which i can update the service?

Comment: Do you mean a WCF RIA service?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a WCF RIA Services Domain Context, then your best bet is to keep your modifications in a separate partial class file.

That way you can recreate the Domain Context when you make data changes (such as your adding of a new field) and not have to do so much reworking to fit it back in.